# In a probability space $(\Omega , \mathcal{F} , P)$, what is the meaning of $P(d w)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

I am reading a book on reinforcement learning. The author says, let $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest sigma-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains all the open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ (which means $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel set). Then the author says, let $X$ be a measurable map from $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}, P)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ (which means $X$ is a random variable). Then he goes on to say that the expected value of $X$ is
\begin{equation}
E(X)=\int_{w\in\Omega} X(w)P(\mathrm{d}w).
\end{equation}

Now the thing I don't understand is, what is $P(\mathrm{d}w)$? Since $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow [0,1]$, and the author is introducing $P(\mathrm{d}w)$, which implies $\mathrm{d}w\in \mathcal{F}$? Then please explain to me how $\mathrm{d}w\in \mathcal{F}$?

My intuition says $E(X)=\int_{w\in\Omega} X(w) P(w)$, not $\int_{w\in\Omega} X(w) P(\mathrm{d}w)$.
I am attaching the screenshot of the book I am reading.

[image]

Comment: By the way: for an element of $\Omega$, you probably want $\omega$ and not $w$.  In TeX, `\omega` yields $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

It is just notation. If $\mu$ is a measure on a measurable space $X$, and $f$ a (complex) measurable function on $X$, we have (by definition)
$$\int_X f d\mu =\int_X f(x)d\mu(x)=\int_X f(x) \mu(dx).$$

Comment: My intuition says $E(X)=\int_{w\in\Omega} X(w) P(w)$, not $\int_{w\in\Omega} X(w) P(\mathrm{d}w)$.

Comment: @RobinKurtz You don’t integrate $P$, you integrate *against* it. So, you needs must have $dP$ or $P(dw)$ or some such similar notation to distinguish. If you integrated $P(w)$ itself, note that often the measure of a singleton is zero so the integral would be zero, which is unhelpful.

Comment: @FShrike ; But then, in $E(X)= \int_{\omega\in \Omega} X(\omega) \mathrm{d}P$, where is the probability involved in computing the expectation?

Comment: @RobinKurtz The probability is involved by definition of a measure theoretic integral. You integrate against the probability measure $P$. That is typically denoted by the addition of $dP$ or $dP(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1):

What Quantum said. Perhaps an explanation for the notation $\int f(x)\;\mu(dx)$:

Approximate $f$ by a simple function; then the integral is approximated by a sum
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_i)\mu(A_i)
$$
where $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ is a partition of $\Omega$ and $x_i \in A_i$.  Now take a "limit", where the partition gets finer, the sets get smaller, and the result is symbolized as
$$
\int_\Omega f(x)\;\mu(dx)
$$
where we think of "$dx$" as a very small set containing $x$.

---

Usefulness of the notation.  Sometimes we have a "transition probabiliy"
in the form $T(x,A)$, where for each fixed $x$, the measure $A \mapsto T(x,A)$ describes probability distribution for the new position one step later.  Then we may want to integrate with respect to that measure, parametrized by $x$.  So we want integrals of the form
$$
\int \phi(x)\;T(x,dx)
$$
to signify, for each $x$,  integration with respect to the measure $A \mapsto T(x,A)$.  I think it would be a bit confusing to write
something like
$$
\text{?}\quad\int\phi(x)\;dT(x,x)
$$

Comment: My only question is why not $E(X)=\int_{w\in\Omega} X(w) P(w)$ rather than $\int_{w\in\Omega} X(w) P(\mathrm{d}w)$?